# SQL query one table multiple choices

Tags: mysql

I need help for designing an SQL statement. It will be created on the fly in a Web Server back end, depending on the request. This will filter a database for the desired results.

To describe my need in simplest form:

One table, two fields, 50 staff, 30 skills.

Example:

```
staff_id, skill_id
1,        1
1,        2
1,        3
1,        4    
2,        2
2,        3
2,        4
3,        2
4,        3
```

Q: Who has Skill 3
A:  Staff 1,2,4
(This is easy)

Q: Who has Skill 2 AND 3
A: Staff 1,2

The actual query will have a request for 5 or 6 Skills

Comment: Thanks @shA.t for cleaning up my post. This is my first post, and I can't seem to get it right :-)

Comment: I may have solved my problem with JOINs as follows 

`code
SELECT SS.staff_id, SS.skill_id

FROM SS 

RIGHT JOIN SS AS SS_1 ON SS.staff_id = SS_1.staff_id 
RIGHT JOIN SS AS SS_2 ON SS_1.staff_id = SS_2.staff_id
WHERE (SS_1.skill_id=2) AND (SS_2.skill_id=3);`

Comment: I just noticed my result is what I wanted, but not what my question asked - now I have a list of the two staff (as per question) _and_  all their skills.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the number of skills varies from time to time, the best way to handle this via temp table..Here is the pseudocode...syntax needs to be fixed.

```
create procedure my_procedure(string of skillsets)
begin
create table #tmp_skillsets(skillset smallint)
foreach skillset in skillsets
    insert into #tmp_skillsets(convert_to_smallint(skillset))

select distinct staff from myTable, #tmp_skillset
where myTable.skillset = #tmp_skillsets

end
```

Call this procedure like: `"exec my_procedure("1456") or "exec my_procedure("179248503")`

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT staff_id
FROM oneTable t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM oneTable ti WHERE t.staff_id = ti.staff_id AND ti.skill_id = 2)
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM oneTable ti WHERE t.staff_id = ti.staff_id AND ti.skill_id = 3)
```